# Kotlin "return" statement for when variable assignment

Tags: kotlin

I want to assign a variable in Kotlin with when:

```kotlin
val clickedBlock: Block? = when (event.action) {
    ...
    Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR -> {
        p.getLineOfSight(null, 5).forEach { block ->
            if (block.type != Material.VOID_AIR) {
                block // I want to assign the variable with this
            }
        }
        null // and not always with this
    }
    else -> null
}
```

But IntelliJ says it would always return the second null value.

How can I achieve it that the variable `clickedBlock` will be assigned with block (and not null) if the if statement inside of the forEach loop is true **without having to introduce another variable**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap this in a [run](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#run) function

```
Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR -> run {
    p.getLineOfSight(null, 5).forEach { block ->
        if (block.type != Material.VOID_AIR) {
            return@run block // I want to assign the variable with this
        }
    }
    null
}
```

but I think it would be better to do this:

```
Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR -> p.getLineOfSight(null, 5).find { block -> block.type != Material.VOID_AIR }
```